# How to modify a variable from nested function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I was trying out a few things with scopes in python and came into a little problem. I have this code here. I want to change the variable `var` from within a nested function.

```
def func_1():
    var = 1
    
    def func_2():
        var = 2
        
    func_2()
    print(var)

func_1()
```

When `func_1()` is run, `var` is still 1. Is it possible to edit `var` under `func_2`?

Comment: I'm downvoting because it took less than a minute of research to find an exact duplicate. Please research before posting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`nonlocal`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement) keyword:

```
def func_1():
    var = 1
    def func_2():
        nonlocal var
        var = 2
    func_2()
    print(var)

func_1() # prints 2
```

Comment: It works, thanks! :D